# How do I find which values are corresponding to the changing values from my phototransistor?

Tags: serial, ir, photoresistor

I am new to using serial input. I have an IR emitter and a photo transistor hooked up to my Arduino, I am trying to see which values corresponds to the colored object I put over my IR emitter and phototransistor.

How do I find which values are corresponding to the changing values from my phototransistor?

Comment: Could you add code and a terminal dump from the monitor please?